# Make two elements sync in html

Tags: html, css

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    .head {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000035;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        clear: left;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;    
    }
    .head a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .head:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .title {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        text-align: center;
        color: #717070;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .title a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #717070;
    }
    #main-content {
        background-color: white;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #menu {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: auto;
        padding-bottom: auto;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #B3B3B3;
        clear: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .secondary_footer div {
        margin: auto;
    }
    #menu div a {
        background-color: #B3B3B3;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 20%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        padding: 30px 0;
        color: #000025;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #menu div a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #B3B3B3;
        background-color: #000025;
    }
    #menu div a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #B3B3B3;
        background-color: #000025;
    }
    #m1:hover + #n1 {
        color: #B3B3B3;
        background-color: #000025;
    }
    #menu div ln {
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: #000025;
        width: 20%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        padding: 30px 0;
        color: #b3b3b3;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {

}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

}

@media (min-width: 1001px) {
}

body {
    background-color: #000025;
}
@charset "UTF-8";
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    #main-content {
        background-color: #000025;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;    
    }
    #main-content:hover {
        background-color: #000
    }
    .projects {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: auto;
        padding-bottom: auto;
        height: 244px;
        clear: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .projects div {
        margin: auto
    }
    .projects div a {
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: #B3B3B3;
        width: 25%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        padding: 30px 0;
        color: #000025;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .projects div a:hover {
        background-color: #000025;
        color: #b3b3b3;
        cursor: context-menu
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {

}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

}

@media (min-width: 1001px) {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lorem ispuim</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="/css-js/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css-js/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/css-js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <header class="head">
                <a href="/"><h1 class="title">Lorem ispuim</h1></a>
            </header>
            <nav class="secondary_header" id="menu">
                <div>
                    <a href="/about" id="m1">ABOUT</a>
                    <a href="/contact" id="m2">CONTACT</a>
                    <ln id="m3">PROJECTS</ln>
                    <a href="Lorem ispuim" id="m4">Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a href="Lorem ispuim" id="m5">Lorem ispuim</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="main-content">
            <nav class="projects">
                <div>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a>Lorem ispuim</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <nav class="secondary_footer" id="menu">
                <div>
                    <a href="/about" id="m1">ABOUT</a>
                    <a href="/contact" id="m2">CONTACT</a>
                    <ln id="m3">PROJECTS</ln>
                    <a href="Lorem ispuim" id="m4">Lorem ispuim</a>
                    <a href="Lorem ispuim" id="m5">Lorem ispuim</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make is so that the ID's #m1, #m2, #m4, #m5 will sync with each other and fade top and bottom when one is hovered over? For Example the `<a href="/about" id="m1">ABOUT</a>` at the top an bottom both shade #000025.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Stackoverflow is forcing me to write more text so I just put Lorem ispuim please ignore that:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo.

Comment: First, regarding the error, you should not try to bypass the filter that way. Instead, try to reduce the amount of code required to reproduce the issue. (that's a little too much CSS);; or describe the code more carefully.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do. When you hover over what, what should be faded? So you want to [[ **when you hover over m1, both m1 and m4 should  be faded** ]], is that correct?

Comment: I mean the id #m1

Comment: with the lots of css there are actually 2 files one after the other

Comment: it will make more sence if you interact with it when it uses more then 1000px as width so just the full page button